# How to remove only pages from Admin Bar?

Tags: pages, admin-bar

How can I remove only pages from Admin Bar?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The menu bar is all controlled by [an object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Admin_Bar) instantiated as `$wp_admin_bar`.

I think this is what you want:

```
function remove_page_menu_wpse_104826() {
  global $wp_admin_bar;
  // var_dump($wp_admin_bar); // debug; uncomment and look at the bottom of the page for the big mess
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-page');
}
add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_page_menu_wpse_104826', 1);
```